# String replacement in pandas dataframe generates "sre_constants.error: unterminated character set" error

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, character

I got a csv file that I am opening with pandas.
One of the columns is named 'standardUpc' and contains data in the format:

`['45783425568']`

I want to remove the two strings: `"['"` and `"']"` so that the standardUpc column only has the value:

`45783425568`

Here is my code:

```
fileloc = "C:/Users/products.csv"
products = pd.read_csv(fileloc)

# COLUMN NAMES ARE: ['productId','title','standardUpc','sellerName','canAddToCart']

# This line only selects conditions where canAddToCart evaluates to True
filtered = (products[(products['canAddToCart'] == True) ])

# Replace the [' and the '] characters in the standardUpc column
filtered["standardUpc"] = filtered["standardUpc"].str.replace("['","")
filtered["standardUpc"] = filtered["standardUpc"].str.replace("']","")

#Now filter further on seller name
filtered_2 =(filtered[(filtered['sellerName'] == 'Robert')])

#print the new dataframe 
for index, row in filtered_2.iterrows(): 
    print (row["productId"], row["sellerName"],row["standardUpc"]) 
#export the filtered dataframe containing the modified UPC string to a new csv file          
filtered_2.to_csv('instock.csv')
```

This generates the error: `sre_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 0` in this line:

```
filtered["standardUpc"] = filtered["standardUpc"].str.replace("['","")
```

Summary:

I want to read a CSV file into a dataframe structure, modify the values in a particular column in that
dataframe, filter the dataframe for certain criteria and then write this all to a new csv file.

I don't want to work on a "view" of the dataframe. I am actually changing values and writing them to a new CSV file.

Comment: how sure are you that it's a string?  It could be a list?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses regular expressions for the `str.replace` method.

That is the reason you are getting the error `sre_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 0` in this line

```
filtered["standardUpc"] = filtered["standardUpc"].str.replace("['","")
```

Use `re.escape` for strings that contain characters with special meaning in regular expressions:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = ['1234', "['456']", '678']

    filtered = pd.DataFrame({'standardUpc': L})
    print(filtered)

    filtered["standardUpc"] = filtered["standardUpc"].str.replace(re.escape("['"), "")
    filtered["standardUpc"] = filtered["standardUpc"].str.replace(re.escape("']"), "")

    print(filtered)
```